# Eclipse: Failed to connect sshd on "hostname" Auth Fail

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, eclipse, authentication

I have the following  [issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8YCH.png)  when I try to start an **ssh interface** (shell) to a Unix host using **Eclipse** (*Remote System Explorer*)

I think that there is an issue related to the (**Generate RSA Key**: Preferences/Network Connection/SSH2).
I tried the below:

a) I've regenerated a new key, saved under:

```
C:\Users\<myUser>\Eclipse\ssh
```

Also I have checked the **Authentication Methods** tab:

**1.gssapi-with-mic
2.  publickey
3.  password
4.  keyboard-interactive**

b) I transferred the public key (again)

c) Configure proxy settings again (Proxy bypass)

d) I added the connections again.

I was using the interface last year on the same computer/ server.

Thanks in advance